# How can the number of files in a directory be determined by viewing "ls -ld" output?

Tags: directory, ls

The command has to be

```
ls -ld
```

Just from viewing the output of this, how can I determine how many files are in this directory?

Comment: Please don't do this: you have already asked this question: reposting it is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

Easily achieve with the power of grep and word count :)  Although are you sure you want the `d` in there?

`ls -ld | grep ^- | wc -l`

Comment: I have stated that the command has to be ls -ld  Can it be determined just from looking at the output?

Answer (score 0):

Without additional arguments, ls -ld will only tell you the permissions of the current directory

```
cd /
ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Oct  7 15:57 .
```

If you want to find the number of entries (files, directories, links) in the current directotry, you can use

```
ls | wc -l
```

or if you just want the number of regular files

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```